# Can't console.log event target name

Tags: javascript

everyone.

I want to console a Continent name when I selected an option in a form. I decided to use e.target.value to get a name, but I faced a problem. I can't get anything in console and I don't know where the problem is.
Here is my code:

```js
const selectPart = document.getElementsByClassName("selectPart");
for (let i = 0; i < selectPart.length; i++) {
  selectPart[i].addEventListener('click', getTarget);
}

function getTarget(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let partName = e.target.value;
  console.log(partName);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="selectForm">
    <option disabled selected class="select">Which continent is your country located in?</option>
    <option class="selectPart">Asia</option>
    <option class="selectPart">Europe</option>
    <option class="selectPart">South America</option>
    <option class="selectPart">North America</option>
    <option class="selectPart">Africa</option>
    <option class="selectPart">Oceania</option>
    <option class="selectPart">Antarctica</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of using Option clicks, use either the "change" or "click" event for the entire <select> element. Simply change to this will fix the issue -> const selectPart=document.getElementsByClassName("selectForm");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with your class name which is `selectForm` and in your code `selectPart`

```js
var select = document.getElementsByClassName('selectForm')[0];

select.addEventListener('change',function(e){
var country = e.target.value;
console.log(country);
});
```

```html
<form>
            <select class="selectForm">
                <option disabled selected class="select">Which continent is your country located in?</option>
                <option class="selectPart">Asia</option>
                <option class="selectPart">Europe</option>
                <option class="selectPart">South America</option>
                <option class="selectPart">North America</option>
      <option class="selectPart">Africa</option>
                <option class="selectPart">Oceania</option>
      <option class="selectPart">Antarctica</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in class name (selectForm and selectPart).
Also 'change' EventListener listens for a changes on select DOM- element and therefore you can access the target value which is selected on change.
Change JS code as following:

```
document.querySelector('.selectForm')
  .addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

Comment: Why is this better? What was wrong with the OPs code?

Comment: Sorry, nothing wrong. Code is just fine. Forgot to mention mistake in class name.